# Check data usage of Guest Network

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, router

I have enabled Guest Network on my tp-link archer c20 router at home. Its open network. I would like to have some way to monitor the data usage on it. Limit the user if he is using too much of the data. I have put speed limit on the guest network of about 5Mbps.

Is it fine to have open guest network?

Comment: How does this relate to Ubuntu ? Guest Network is handled by your router, not your machine or OS.

Comment: I wanted to monitor usage from my computer which has ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Seems less an Ubuntu issue and more a functionality of your router issue, how does this issue relate to the usage and functionality of Ubuntu? Wireless usage would be a functionality of the router as your Ubuntu is not routing or managing the traffic is it?